# What is this bug? Singapore

Tags: species-identification, species

[image]
enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Around 1 inch in length

Comment: is this all the information you have? one inch long and lives in singapore :)

Comment: I have the pictures. What more should I include?

Comment: please take a look here https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: does the bug live in water or on land,what type of habitat,indoors or outdoors,did you see it at night or during the day.simply any details you can provide will help us help you.

Comment: Looks like an Orthoptera species.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [orthopteran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoptera) insect. Well known members of this insect order are grasshoppers, locusts and crickets.
You can recognize them by their

- greatly developed [femurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod_leg#Femur) specifically adapted for jumping,
- hardened forewings (called [tegmina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_wing#Orthoptera)), which protect the membranous hindwings folded beneath them,
- long, filamentous antennae,
- two [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus) (appendages at the tip of the abdomen),
- chewing mouthparts (with which they chew on plant material such as leaves and stems) and
- prominent compound eyes.

Orthopterans undergo incomplete metamorphosis, progressing through egg, nymph and adult stages. Nymphs closely resemble adults, but lack fully developped wings and reproductive structures. As this specimen has fully developped wings, we can conclude it must be an adult.

Moreover, I assume this specimen belongs to the suborder [Caelifera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caelifera) as antenna are shorter than the body (as opposed to their sister taxon [Ensifera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensifera) which have more-than-body-long antenna).

[image: Orthoptera labeled bodyparts]